# Solving coupled ODEs with complex values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working on solving the coupled equations below:

```
from scipy.integrate import complex_ode
import numpy as np

A = 1
B = -1j
C = -1
D = -2
E = -1j

def system(z, t):
    x, y = z[0], z[1]
    dxdt  = A*x + B*y + C
    dydt  = D*y + E*x
    return [dxdt, dydt]

t = np.linspace(0, 300., 1000)

x0, y0 = 0.0, 0.0
sol =  complex_ode(system, [x0, y0], t)
```

I keep getting the message :

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lg.py", line 21, in <module>
    sol =  complex_ode(system, [x0, y0], t)
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)"
```

Can anyone tell me why I see this error?

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.complex_ode.html)? Take a look at the arguments in the docs, and take a look at the arguments you're providing. There's a discrepancy.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `complex_ode` as if it had the same interface as `odeint` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).  That won't work. `complex_ode` uses the same interface as the `ode` class (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html).  (As an alternative, you could try `odeintw` (https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw).)